# xcode 4 - linking to view out of navigation controller in tab controller

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller

i have a tab bar in which i have included a navigation controller. with this navigation controller i open a new site. this new site contains buttons which should open other sites. but when i am clicking on these buttons an error occurs:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController buttonPushTestList:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4eac880'
```

opened site with navigation controller in tab controller contains the following code:

.h file:

```
- (IBAction) buttonPushTestList:(id)sender;
```

.m file:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPushTestList:(id)sender {

UIViewController *testlist = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"TestList" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: testlist animated:YES];
```

}

what i am doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 2):

You're using an instance of UIViewController.  You should be using an instance of your *subclass* of UIViewController.

You have some class, which I suspect is a subclass of UIViewController.  On that class you have defined a method `buttonPushListTest:`.  You didn't tell us the name of that class, so I'm going to call it JasminViewController.

I assume you have a nib with a button, and you have configured that button to send the `buttonPushListTest:` message to a target. The nib thinks that the class of the target is JasminViewController.

However, at runtime, the target of the button is *not* a JasminViewController.  At runtime, the target is a plain old UIViewController.  You can tell because the error message says UIViewController.

So, there is a place in your program where you are creating the object the be ones the target of the button.  You should be creating a JasinViewController as the target, but instead you are creating a plain old UIViewController.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you right.. what do I have to change?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. May it be possible to send you my Xcode project? This is urgent for me, as it is for a school project..

Comment: Then you should have used the "homework" tag, and you should ask your instructor or TA for help.